# Schema Registry - Register a custom Object Type

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I want to register an Avro schema which references another Avro schema on the schema registry.

First I've registered the following base Avro schema:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"Client",
  "namespace":"com.test.client",
  "doc": "Client Property specific information is specified in this object",
  "fields" : [
      {"name" : "name", "type" : [ "null", "string" ]},
      {"name" : "address", "type" :  [ "null", "string"]}
  ]
}
```

Them if I try to register the following Avro schema which refers to the base one within 'client' attribute the operation fails with error 422

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"AnotherObject",
  "namespace":"com.test.client",
  "fields":
  [
    {"name":"tenant", "type": [ "null", "long" ]},
    {"name":"client", "type" : [ "null","com.test.client.Client"]}
  ]
}
```

It seems issue is related to specifying custom type fields.

**Any idea how to add custom type while registering related schemas in schema registry?**

Comment: Ideally, you'd nest the complete object, but I know references were recently added to the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **schema references** to let a schema to refer to other schemas on the Confluent Schema Registry.

> Note that support for this notation has been introduced with
> Confluent Platform **5.5**.

Basing on your example ( according to the documentation available at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#subjects) you should register the `AnotherObject` using the following payload on the POST request for new schemas registration:

```
{
  "schema":"{
     \"type\":\"record\",
     \"name\":\"AnotherObject\",
     \"namespace\":\"com.test.client\",
     \"fields\":[
        {
           \"name\":\"tenant\",
           \"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]
        },
        {
           \"name\":\"client\",
           \"type\":[\"null\",\"com.test.client.Client\"]
        }
     ]
   }",
  "schemaType":"AVRO",
  "references":[
    {
      "name":"com.test.client.Client",
      "subject":"clientSubject",
      "version":1
    }
  ]
}
```

Where **clientSubject** is the subject name you specified on registering the `com.test.client.Client` schema.

As you can see basically with this approach you can specify directly the version of the reference schema to use. This is very useful because otherwise inconsistency could occurs.

Check the documentation for further informations about schema references at the following link: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html#referenced-schemas-avro

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i was looking for